# Restrict Access to folders in apache with URLs rewriting by CMS

Tags: apache

This is pretty simple but I can't figure how to get it work.
I have a simple folder structure:

```
/var/www/html/test
              ├── .htaccess
              ├── images
              ├── index.php
              ├── public
              ├── secret
              │   └── secret_file1
              └── secret2
                  └── secret_file2
```

I would like my website to be accessible via http://my-website.org or http://my-website.org/index.php

I use a CMS that uses URL rewriting via .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$   index.php?uri=/$1    [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

So http://my-website.org/login becomes http://my-website.org/index.php?login

I would like to protect the folders secret and secret2, and an possible future secret3, secretX, and so on. Those folders to protect can have any name, so a

```
Require all denied
```

default policy seems to be the most appropriated

I want index.php, images folder, public1 folder and the URL rewrited (/login /history, etc.) to be accessible.

I've tried:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/test>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/test/images>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

But that doesn't handle URL rewriting.